# Magento 2 Content Staging Dashboard

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.3

I am using `Magento 2.2.3`. As you know we can see the promotion rules status at `Content -> Dashboard`.

But when I delete some promotion rules it is still showing in the dashboard. I have cleared the cache, run the cron and reindexing but content stating dashboard is not updating.

Do you have any clue why it does not update?

Comment: any luck? I am facing the same issues.